# Binding BindingList<string[]> to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Situation:

I am attempting to bind a `BindingList<string[]>` constructed from a LINQ to SQL query to a `DataGridView`.

Problem:

I either cannot make modification to the `DataGridView` after items are generated -or- I get a bunch of unwanted fields in my `DataGridView` (it depends on which iteration of my code I use) I have googled as hard as I can and tried implementing most of the solutions I have found online to no avail.

I know that string has no public property for its actual value. I am having a difficult time determining how to retrieve that (I believe is part of the problem).

C#

```
int item = (from p in CurrentConversion.Companies[lbCompanies.SelectedIndex].Modules 
    where p.ModuleName.Equals(clbModules.SelectedItem) 
    select p.ModuleId)
    .FirstOrDefault();

BindingList<string[]> Data = new BindingList<string[]>((
    from p in CurrentConversion.Companies[lbCompanies.SelectedIndex].QuestionAnswers
    where p[2].Equals(item)
    select new string[] { p[0].ToString(), p[3].ToString() })
    .ToList());

dgvQuestions.DataSource = Data;
dgvQuestions.Refresh();
```

Unwanted Behavior:

This occurs after binding

[image: datagridview]

Question:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I fix it?

Additional Information:

I am not sure what additional information may be need but I will supply what is requested.

Also if I switch to my other code iteration:

```
int item = (from p in CurrentConversion.Companies[lbCompanies.SelectedIndex].Modules where p.ModuleName.Equals(clbModules.SelectedItem) select p.ModuleId).FirstOrDefault();
            var Data = new BindingList<object>((from p in CurrentConversion.Companies[lbCompanies.SelectedIndex].QuestionAnswers where p[2].Equals(item) select new {Question = p[0].ToString(), Answer = p[3].ToString() }).Cast<object>().ToList());
            dgvQuestions.DataSource = Data;
            dgvQuestions.Refresh();
            dgvQuestions.Columns[1].ReadOnly = false;
```

I can see the data properly but I cannot edit the column I would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to a list of string arrays, and you are getting the properties form the array. Most likely you want something like the following:

```
var Data = new BindingList<object>((
    from p in CurrentConversion.Companies[lbCompanies.SelectedIndex].QuestionAnswers 
    where p[2].Equals(item) 
    select new {
                Val1 = p[0].ToString(), 
                Val2 = p[3].ToString() 
               }).ToList());
```

Comment: Perhaps if you instead of object create your own class and use that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing those fields in the Grid is that you're binding each row to a `string[]`.  So it is automatically displaying the properties of `string[]` as the columns. There is no built-in logic for the grid to parse an array and use the contents of the array as columns.

In order to get the `DataGrid` to display your data correctly, you should bind it to a custom type, and it will use the public properties of the type as columns.